# LuaDec for LuaJIT?

Tags: lua, декомпиляция, luajit

Подскажите, как адаптировать декомпилятор LuaDec к скриптам LuaJIT
Один парень каким-то образом декомпилирует LuaJIT скрипты, используя этот декомпилятор, но не хочет говорить, как

LuaJIT 2.1.0-бета3

```
>luadec Fram.luac
luadec: Fram.luac: not a precompiled chunk
```

Comment: Судя по [докам](https://github.com/viruscamp/luadec/wiki/LuaJIT-2.0-Bytecode), LuaDec понимает байткод LuaJIT. С чем конкретно у вас возникли проблемы?

Comment: https://i.vgy.me/pSWJjO.png
Сам скрипт: https://fex.net/s/yeaccc2

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что LuaDec из коробки не умеет декомпилировать скрипты LuaJIT, не смотря на то, что в вики и приведено описание байткода.

Но хорошая новость в том, что для LuaJIT есть свой рабочий декомпилятор: https://gitlab.com/znixian/luajit-decompiler

Чтобы декомпилировать скрипт, нужно установить python3 и выполнить в консоли команду:

```
python3 ./main.py -f Fram.luac > Fram.lua
```

С вашим скриптом справляется на ура:

```
script_name("\\xd2\\xe5\\xeb\\xe5\\xef\\xee\\xf0\\xf2 \\xed\\xe0 \\xec\\xe5\\xf2\\xea\\xf3: Evolve-Rp")
script_version("Latest Version")
script_author("Ded_Fedot")
require("lib.moonloader")
require("lib.sampfuncs")

function main()
    if not isSampfuncsLoaded() or not isSampLoaded() then
        return
    end

    while not isSampAvailable() do
        wait(200)
    end

    sampRegisterChatCommand("dedtp", teleport)
    sampAddChatMessage("{00D5FF}[Evolve-Rp] {FFFFFF}\\xd2\\xe5\\xeb\\xe5\\xef\\xee\\xf0\\xf2 \\xed\\xe0 {FFE741}\\xec\\xe5\\xf2\\xea\\xf3", 54783)
    sampAddChatMessage("{00D5FF}[Evolve-Rp] {FFFFFF}\\xc0\\xe2\\xf2\\xee\\xf0: {EE0047}Ded_Fedot", 54783)

    while true do
        wait(0)

        if activ == true then
            tpoot = true
            stpoot = true

            wait(1000)
            requestCollision(posX, posY)
            loadScene(posX, posY, posZ)

            posZ = getGroundZFor3dCoord(posX, posY, 500)

            setCharCoordinates(playerPed, posX, posY, posZ)
            wait(2000)

            tpoot = false

            wait(1000)

            stpoot = false
            activ = false

            addOneOffSound(0, 0, 0, 1139)
            printStringNow("~w~Teleport ~g~Successful~n~~y~by ~p~Ded_Fedot", 3000)
        end
    end
end

function teleport()
    metka, posX, posY, posZ = getTargetBlipCoordinates()

    if metka then
        activ = true
        tpoot = true
        stpoot = true
    else
        sampAddChatMessage("\\xcf\\xee\\xf1\\xf2\\xe0\\xe2\\xfc \\xec\\xe5\\xf2\\xea\\xf3... {EE0047}\\xcc\\xf3\\xe4\\xe8\\xeb\\xe0", -1)
        addOneOffSound(0, 0, 0, 1138)
    end
end

function onSendPacket(slot0)
    if slot0 == 207 and tpoot == true then
        return false
    end
end

function onReceiveRpc(slot0)
    if slot0 == 12 and stpoot == true then
        return false
    end
end
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я в курсе о этом декомпиляторе, он никак не связан тем - что мне нужно. Почему я указал изначально, что именно через LuaDec мне нужно декомпилировать, потому что парень который мне сказал, что он с помощью LuaDec'а декомпилирует LuaJIT скрипты, он получает в итоге полный, рабочий исходный код. Да, этот декомпилятор тоже так умеет, но только с маленькими скриптами, один вы декомпилировали выше. При декомпиляции большого скрипта, на выходе уже получается неработоспособный код.

Comment: Я вообще без понятие как он это делает, вот всё что он упомянул "имена переменных, функций - будет вернуть невозможно, но скрипт будет исполнятся после декомпиляции". Вот большой скрипт, можете сами убедиться, что декомпилятор выше который вы кинули, не работает так - как я указал.
https://fex.net/s/4pf1rz9

Comment: @Max Да, всё так, этот декомпилятор не идеален. Но похоже, что лучшего в открытом доступе нету. Парень запросто мог написать свой декомпилятор на базе LuaDec, но вам это никак не поможет - если он не хочет делиться своей работой, то вам придётся брать и писать с нуля. Либо можно заглянуть в код открытого и более-менее рабочего декомпилятора по ссылке выше и попробовать улучшить его. Тем более, что там Python, а не Си, как в случае с LuaDec.

Comment: @Max А может он не декомпилирует, а дизассемблирует их? Он вам сами скрипты показывал?

Comment: Показывал. Всё так и есть

Comment: Как с вами можно связаться, на сайте нету личных сообщений тут.

Comment: @Max *"Всё так и есть"* это как? Дизассемблирует? Тогда всё очень просто, ведь LuaJIT сама [умеет это](http://luajit.org/running.html): `luajit -bl xxx.luac xxx.txt`. И точно так же, как и в случае с luac, этот байткод может быть запущен на выполнение (после необходимых правок).

Comment: Можно только запустить, обратно скомпилировать нельзя?

Comment: @Max Оказывается, я неправильно понял документацию: ни запустить, ни скомпилировать дизассемблированный код нельзя (внезапно!), на него можно только посмотреть: [How to run LuaJIT bytecode generated from `luajit -bl`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43155548)

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Оригинальный LuaDec первоначально был написан для Lua 5.0.2.
Сейчас имеется несколько сотен его форков для более позднихз версий Lua.
Вполне возможно, что один из них действительно умеет разбирать байткод LuaJIT, попробую задействовать поздние версии